# curve() does not add curve to my plot when "add = TRUE"

Tags: r, plot

I have a very simple problem that I can't seem to figure out. I want to plot two equations in one graph. I've tried `add = TRUE` but this doesn't seem to work.

```
curve(0.044*x+1.638)
curve(0.3438*x+0.5155, add=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, actually, the `curve` does work, but you can not see it. To explain this, we add a few more lines of code:

```
f1 <- function(x) 0.044*x+1.638
f2 <- function(x) 0.3438*x+0.5155
x0 <- seq(0, 1, by = 0.1)
```

I have defined your example functions by `f1` and `f2`. I also take 11 sampling points between `[0,1]` to evaluate and plot. Why this range? Because without specification via arguments `from`, `to` (see `?curve`), `curve` will make plot on this range.

Now, let's see this:

```
>f1(x0)
[1] 1.6380 1.6424 1.6468 1.6512 1.6556 1.6600 1.6644 1.6688 1.6732 1.6776
[11] 1.6820
 > f2(x0)
[1] 0.51550 0.54988 0.58426 0.61864 0.65302 0.68740 0.72178 0.75616 0.79054
[10] 0.82492 0.85930
```

The function value of `f1` is so much higher than `f2`. When you call `curve` for the first time to plot `f1`, it will fix the `ylim` to show roughly to the range of `f1(x)`. Therefore, when you add `f2(x)`, it will not be seen in this `ylim`.

Try this instead, by first choosing a shared `ylim`:

```
ylim <- range(c(f1(x0), f2(x0)))
curve(f1, ylim = ylim)
curve(f2, add=TRUE, col = "red")
```

[image: Plot]

**This kind of problem is a common pitfall.** When you decide to plot several objects on a single graph, you need to set the appropriate `xlim` and `ylim` that's large enough to hold all objects. Don't expect R to adjust these "on the fly"; it can not do this. Plotting range is determined when the first plot is made.

Comment: Excellent explanation, particularly the last paragraph. +1