# R: abline does not add line to my graph

Tags: r, plot

I try to draw line graph using R. The lines have been plotted, but the `abline` line doesn't show up.

```
M <- c(1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3)
y <- c(0.0466,0.0522,0.0608,0.0629,0.0660)
plot(M, y, type="l", col="red", xlab="sdr",
     ylab="simulated type I error rate")
abline(h=c(0.025,0.075),col=4,lty=2)
```

This is my simple coding for the graph. Any ways to make the line pop out?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
M <- c(1.0,1.5,2.0,2.5,3)
y <- c(0.0466,0.0522,0.0608,0.0629,0.0660)
plot(M, y, type="l",col="red",xlab="sdr", ylim = c(0.025, 0.075),
     ylab="simulated type I error rate")
abline(h=c(0.025,0.075),col=4,lty=2)
```

by using `ylim`.

I would refer you to read my answer for another post: [curve() does not add curve to my plot when “add = TRUE”](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37198610/4891738) for more about setting `ylim` when plotting several objects on a graph.